# Difference between "verb-agreement" and "subject-verb-agreement" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

It seems that we have two tags, [**subject-verb-agreement**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subject-verb-agreement) and [**verb-agreement**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb-agreement) for similar questions. I briefly read some questions under them and I don't see much difference. Am I missing something? How about combining the two?

Today, a tag named [**superfluity**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/superfluity) was created and is it necessary to have it when we have a tag [**redundancy**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redundancy)?

16.09.2016: All synonyms are in place.

Comment: Take, for example, [*It's better **to have** one of our allies close to us than **having** none at all.*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256948/) It's been closed anyway, but I'd say it would be perfectly reasonable to tag that question with ***verb agreement***, even though it's not a matter of ***subject** verb agreement*.

Comment: Lumpers vs splitters.  I don't know which I prefer when classifying species, but for tags, lumping is better than splitting.  There are too many tags!

Comment: There is no difference between "subject-verb-agreeement" and "verb-agreement" in English. However, it's hard to get tags merged. I asked a question about tag synonyms [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7201/obvious-tag-synonyms-that-i-dont-have-enough-tag-rep-to-suggest), and tchrist asked  one long ago [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4442/the-great-elu-tag-clean-up-proposal-of-2014), but there are still some suggestions from those questions that are not implemented.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't think that question ought to be tagged with verb agreement. It's asking about gerunds and infinitives, or parallel structure. But to avoid edge cases where verb agreement occurs without being subject-verb agreement, it's simple to just merge "subject-verb agreement into "verb-agreement."

Comment: @sumelic Thanks for the links. Do you find this question a duplicate? I agree with ab2 and I also think there are too many tags in this community.  I agree with your suggestion to merge "subject-verb-agreement" into "verb-agreement".

Comment: I don't know if it's a duplicate. Hopefully I'll be able to vote to merge "subject-verb-agreement" in a day or so; I now have [five questions with an upvote in the tag](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A77227+%5Bsubject-verb-agreement%5D), which should be sufficient once the system updates my calculated tag reputation.

Comment: @sumelic Can you show me the link how **vote to merge** works? I'd like to see if I am allowed to do that with my reputation points or tag reputation. I have never heard of it.

Comment: You should be able to vote here, if you have enough tag rep: http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/verb-agreement/synonyms

Comment: @sumelic Thanks for the link. Do I need to type "subject-verb-agreement" in the box and click on **suggest**?

Comment: @Rathony: exactly

Comment: @sumelic I've just tried it, but it says **Creating a tag system requires 5 score in this tag**. I don't think I can do it. Good luck.

Comment: @sumelic I did. Now I understand why you edited my answers. We need one more vote, I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have now suggested [subject-verb-agreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subject-verb-agreement) as a synonym for [verb-agreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb-agreement). If this suggestion is accepted, then in the future all questions that people try to tag with [subject-verb-agreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subject-verb-agreement) will be automatically re-tagged with [verb-agreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb-agreement).

In order to accomplish this, at least four other people with an answer score of 5 or greater in the [verb-agreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/verb-agreement) tag need to vote up the suggestion. Three people have done so already, so we only need one more! They can do that from here: https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/verb-agreement/synonyms

If you don't know what your score is in this tag, you can see it from the "tags" tab on your profile. There is also a list of top answerers for the tag: https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/verb-agreement/topusers

While we're on the subject of agreement and tag synonyms, it seems to me that [concord](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/concord) ("Questions about grammatical agreement") should be made a synonym of [agreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/agreement). Anyone with the requisite reputation can suggest that here: https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/agreement/synonyms

Comment: Thank you for your answer and efforts.

Comment: Just curious - why make verb-agreement the primary tag rather than subject-verb-agreement? Is it just for length, or is the simpler *verb-agreement* more idiomatic in linguistics?

Comment: @Lawrence: basically, it's so that if there's any odd type of verb agreement that isn't with the subject, we'll still have a tag that covers it. Araucaria pointed out to me that the phenomenon of [proximity agreement](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/proximityagreement.htm) can sometimes cause a verb to be used that does not agree with the subject.